# Incorrect plot being displayed using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I am doing a time series analysis:

`interval_data_file.csv` is a csv file, with two columns: `Time` and `Freq`.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 300, 20

DATETIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
INPUT_FILE = 'interval_data_file.csv'


dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, DATETIME_FORMAT)
data = pd.read_csv(INPUT_FILE, parse_dates=True, index_col='Time',
                   date_parser=dateparse)


print data.index

ts = data['Freq']
#print ts.head(10)

print ts['1970-02-04 20:12:16']

plt.plot(ts)
plt.show()
```

This is the plot outputted which is obviously wrong:

[image]

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think the output plot is wrong? Looking at your data, it seems pretty correct.

Comment: Since you already have frequency counts, did you give `bar` plot a try which seems ideal for such a purpose and see if you get the right results? You need to do - `plt.bar(ts.index, ts)` if you intend on doing via `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are not sorting your index. Try:

```
data.sort_index(inplace=True)
```